# How to uninstall Roblox?

Tags: 14.04, software-center

So I for some reason installed ROBLOX and now it updates automatically every time I open Ubuntu Software Center. I need it gone from my computer. I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Apparently Roblox is a pain kill on every platform...

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove ROBLOX open a Terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo apt-get purge roblox
```

The `purge` command will (from `manpage`):

```
Purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```